# Fixing window counter-balance cord

Tags: windows, window-frame

I'm wondering if anyone is familiar with the style of window counter-balance cords that just run straight from frame around the window pane into the frame at the very top, with no clear pull-outs, notches, screws, etc. (i.e., no visible way of accessing/adjusting the cord). I have some that need adjustment/replacement, but they don't seem to resemble the other styles I've seen on the internet. Perhaps I pry the top section off? It is not clear and I don't want to damage anything. [image: image of cord and window]

Answer (score 1):

If the window is an Andersen window, the ballast will be under the vinyl cover at the top of the window. The edge of the cover is covered by the trim at the top, where the cover makes a corner to wrap around and go under the trim. Sometimes the edge can be coaxed out from under the trim, it does not go under far at all. Here is a tutorial on Youtube that will fill in the rest.

[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KvjMG0IAWk)

Comment: Thank you! As far as I can tell, these are Andersen® 200 Series Perma-Shield® Narroline® double-hung windows. I will see what I can do as far as repairs, but this seems to give me all the info I need. Thank you again!

Comment: I had Andersens in my home. It is easy to trash the side tracks on the way out, or on the way back in. And do be careful when you pull the ends of the cord out the sash, there is a lot of pull.

Answer (score 0):

In the traditional wooden windows I've worked with, if you removed the trim and stops you could then remove the windows sashes, which gave you access to a panel at the bottom that could be removed to access the weight chamber. In those, assuming the rope came free of the weight: Work a new rope through, tie the weight to its end, adjust the attachment to the sash so the weight is at or near the top of the chamber when the sash is at the bottom of its travel, reassemble everything by reversing the disassembly.

There may be other designs.